# Filter array of objects by other object via value of same property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I want to filter JSON data, which I use to dynamically create a table with, by text input fields. Each table header has it's own input field.

Imagine table data like so:

```
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    A: "10",
    B: "100",
    C: "1000",
    description: "number 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    A: "20",
    B: "200",
    C: "2000",
    description: "number 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    A: "30",
    B: "300",
    C: "3000",
    description: "number 3"
  }
]
```

My input is stored in a separate object like so:

```
var filterColumnKeys = {
  A: "20",
  B: "43"
}
```

This object contains the search inputs (values) and keys based on the headers of the table (which get created dynamically by the table data).

I need to filter each object in table data with these two search inputs (20 and 43), so only objects (= rows of the table) who match the search input are shown. The filterting should be instant while typing so a partially matching phrase should be shown, too.

Example #1: nothing would be shown:

```
var filterColumnKeys = {
  A: "20",
  B: "43"
}
```

Example #2: the object with id 2 would be shown:

```
var filterColumnKeys = {
  A: "20",
}
```

Example #3: all objects would be shown:

```
var filterColumnKeys = {
  B: "00",
}
```

EDIT: I already have function to filter the whole table with ONE filter key:

```
// filter whole table by filter input field
if (filterKey) {
  data = data.filter(function(item) {
    var dataKeys = Object.keys(item);
    return dataKeys.some(function(key) {
      var itemValue = String(item[key]).toLowerCase();
      // int (-1 if not found)
      var itemFound = itemValue.indexOf(filterKey);
      var shouldBeFiltered = itemFound > -1;
      return shouldBeFiltered;
    });
  });
}
```

..but defining it to only check each input with the corresponding data object via the key (=column of table) doesn't work when using each key of the `filterColumnKeys` array.

Comment: `data.filter(e => Object.keys(filterColumnKeys).every(prop => e[prop] === filterColumnKeys[prop]));` I got a bit confused there because your examples have strings instead of numbers, i assume that is simply a typo.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks, but nothing is shown when I try to use that (so everything is filtered). It seems to not work for substrings (like in my example #3)? When I paste a whole search phrase instead of typing it, it works.

Comment: You added the later examples after i had already written the code, and nowhere else in the question mention anything about partial matching.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Sorry, you're right, I added it now.

Comment: Oddly enough, even then, none of the array elements has an `A` which contains `"00"`, so i still don't really know by what criteria it should match that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Right again, changed it to "B" in the example.

Comment: `data.filter(e => Object.keys(filterColumnKeys).every(prop => e[prop].includes(filterColumnKeys[prop])));` - note that this requires all related properties to be strings, or there will be no `includes`. Also note that it's a bit uncommon to write the end of the search term and it still autocompletes (the `B` properties don't start with `"00"` but end with it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and inspiration, I modified [ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte)'s comment of my initial question and modified it a bit:

```
  if (filterColumnKeys) {
    if (Object.keys(filterColumnKeys).length !== 0) {
      data = data.filter(e =>
        Object.keys(filterColumnKeys).every(key =>
          String(e[key])
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(String(filterColumnKeys[key]).toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

One of my main problems was the disappear of the table headers. Every time the search phrase didn't match any data with the first input, the table headers get hidden, which also hides the text input fields, so the phrase couldn't be changed.

I added checks to prevent the header hiding and the phrase-value match check is done with lower case strings.

I can also use multiple input fields to filter the data (also with partially matching phrases) at the same time with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

[try solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esbgbu)

TS:

```
A:any='';
  B:any='';

  arr: Array<any> = [{
    id: "1",
    A: "10",
    B: "100",
    C: "1000",
    description: "number 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    A: "20",
    B: "200",
    C: "2000",
    description: "number 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    A: "30",
    B: "300",
    C: "3000",
    description: "number 3"
  }
  ]

  data: any;
  filterData(a,b){

    if(a == "00" || b == "00"){
    this.data = this.arr;
    } else if( a == '' || b == ''){
    this.data = this.data = this.arr.find(obj => obj.A == a || obj.B == b)

    } else if( a != '' && b != '' ){
    this.data = this.arr.find(obj => obj.A == a && obj.B == b)

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and loop through each item and check if they have corresponding keys and values in them:

```
var data=[{id:"1",A:"10",B:"100",C:"1000",description:"number 1"},{id:"2",A:"20",B:"200",C:"2000",description:"number 2"},{id:"3",A:"30",B:"300",C:"3000",description:"number 3"}];

var filterColumnKeys = {
  A: "20"
}


function getFilteredData(data, filterColumnKeys) {

    const fKeys = Object.keys(filterColumnKeys);

    const filtered = data.filter(item => {

        const isMatch = fKeys.every(k => {
            return filterColumnKeys[k] === '00' || item[k] === filterColumnKeys[k];
        })

        return isMatch;

    });

    return filtered;

}

const result = getFilteredData(data, filterColumnKeys);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Same problem: It works when I paste a whole search phrase in the input field, but it doesn't work for typing, as partially matching phrases get filtered.

Comment: @BennettDams can you give an example of the search phrase?

Comment: Literally any string or number, as the phrases come from an text input field.